# Does GC collect objects that reference a socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, garbage-collection, circular-reference

Will GC ever collect `OBS` object `obs`?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateSOB();
            Form form = new Form();
            form.Show();
            GC.Collect();
            Application.Run();
        }

        static void CreateSOB()
        {
            SOB sop = new SOB();
        }

        public class SOB
        {
            private Socket socket;

            public SOB()
            {
                socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.IP);
                socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 12345));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), buffer);
            }

            public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("recv:" + socket.EndReceive(ar).ToString());
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), buffer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, `CreateSOB()` creates a local variable `sob` of type `SOB` which in turn creates a socket and keeps a reference to it.

Since no thread keeps a direct reference to object `sob`, will it ever be collected by GC?

Comment: Well, you've got asynchronous calls keeping it alive, I suspect - but without actually doing anything useful beyond calling `MessageBox.Show`. And if `EndReceive` ever threw an exception (preventing the next BeginReceive call) then both the SOB and Socket would be eligible for garbage collection. At least, that's my quick reading of it...

Comment: if the `SOB` can see the `Socket` and the `Socket` can see the `SOB`, then as long as one of them is reachable: both will be kept alive. In this case, it is **likely** that the unmanaged part of `Socket` code and the registered IO callback will act to root it, but frankly you'd do better to explicitly track the objects yourself

Comment: Your buffer byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; is a local variable so it is disposed on the return from ReceiveCallback.  For it to be return it should in the ar parameter and not the local varaible.

Comment: @jdweng no, it isn't; a: it isn't disposable, b: neither GC nor dispose happens at the return (just... sometime after), and c: the reference to the array is held by the async operation; it *should* be possible to reuse the same buffer between operations, to make this simpler, though

Comment: @jdweng This is just a theoretical example. Ignore buffer or other aspects of the implementation. I'm strictly interested  in `obs` object life cycle.

Comment: @Marc Gravell : any variables in a method on the execution stack is not valid after you return from the method.  Look closely. buffer is defined in two different methods.

Comment: @jdweng variables aren't objects; the GC doesn't collect variables, it collects objects; the object is passed *in* to the async IO API, and it is *that* which keeps the buffer (the one created *before* each `BeginReceive`) alive